# What is the zero-truncated Poisson distribution used for? And how is the mean and variance derived?

Tags: self-study, distributions, econometrics, poisson-distribution

I know that the density looks like this: $P(Y=y) = \frac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^y}{y!(1-e^{-\lambda})}$
and from wikipedia that the mean and variance like this:

$$\operatorname E(Y) = \frac{\lambda}{1-e^{-\lambda}}$$

$$ \operatorname{Var}(Y) = \frac{\lambda + \lambda^2}{1-e^{- \lambda}} - \frac{\lambda^2}{(1-e^{- \lambda})^2}$$

But how have the mean and variance been derived?

Comment: Do you also seek for usual Poisson mean/variance derivation?

Comment: If you only get a report when something is counted, then the reports are zero-truncated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\e}{\operatorname E}\newcommand{\v}{\operatorname{var}}$[This](http://www.stat.umn.edu/geyer/8053/slides/aster.pdf) appears to include one or more applications of the zero-truncated Poisson distribution in applied statistics.

Suppose $X\sim\operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda)$ and $Y= \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } X=0, \\ 0 & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases}$

The zero-truncated Poisson distribution is the conditional distribution of $X$ given then event $Y=0.$ So we seek $\e(X\mid Y=0)$ and $\v(X\mid Y=0).$

First, apply the [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation):
\begin{align}
& \lambda =\e(X) = \e(\e(X\mid Y)) \\[6pt]
= {} & \e(X\mid Y=0)\Pr(Y=0) + \e(X\mid Y=1)\Pr(Y=1) \\[6pt]
= {} & \e(X\mid Y=0)(1-e^{-\lambda}) + 0.
\end{align}
So we have
$$
\lambda =\e(X\mid Y=0)(1-e^{-\lambda} )
$$
and therefore
$$
\e(X\mid Y=0) = \frac \lambda {1-e^{-\lambda}},
$$
or, if you like,
$$
\e(X\mid Y=0) = \frac{\lambda e^\lambda}{e^\lambda -1}.
$$
Next apply the [law of total variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance):
$$
\lambda = \v(X) = \v(\e(X\mid Y)) + \e(\v(X\mid Y)). \tag 0
$$
And
\begin{align}
\e(\v(X\mid Y)) = {} & \v(X\mid Y=0)\Pr(Y=0) \\
& {} + \v(X\mid Y=1)\Pr(Y=1) \\[6pt]
= {} & \v(X\mid Y=0) (1-e^{-\lambda}) + 0. \tag 1
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\v(\e(X\mid Y)) = {} & \v\left.\begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } Y = 1, \\ \lambda/(1-e^{-\lambda}) & \text{if } Y=0 \end{cases} \right\} \\[10pt]
= {} & \Pr(Y=0)\cdot\Pr(Y=1) \cdot \left( \frac \lambda {1-e^{-\lambda}} \right)^2 \\[8pt]
= {} & (1-e^{-\lambda}) e^{-\lambda} \cdot \left( \frac \lambda {1-e^{-\lambda}} \right)^2 \tag 2
\end{align}
So the sum of the two quantities on lines $(1)$ and $(2)$ above is equal, as stated on line $(0),$ to $\lambda.$ From that you can deduce $\v(X\mid Y=0),$ the variance of the truncated Poisson distribution.

Comment: How do you know $Pr(Y=0)=(1-e^{-\lambda})$ without knowing the distribution of $Y$?

Comment: @DeepNorth : I said $$X\sim\operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda)$$ and $$Y= \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } X=0, \\ 0 & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases}$$  That tells you the distribution of $Y. \qquad$

Comment: @DeepNorth : $\ldots\ldots\,$in particular, it tells you that $\Pr(Y=1) = \Pr(X=0)$ and $\Pr(Y=0) = 1 - \Pr(X=0). \qquad$

Answer (score 2):

Note that your PMF is $p(y)=\frac{f(y)}{1-e^{-\lambda}}$, for $y>0$,  where $f(y)$ is the PMF of normal Poisson.
Then,

$$\operatorname E[Y]=\sum_{y=1}^\infty y \frac{f(y)}{1-e^{-\lambda}}=\frac{1}{1-e^{-\lambda}}\sum_{y=1}^\infty y f(y)=\frac{1}{1-e^{-\lambda}}\underbrace{\sum_{y=0}^\infty yf(y)}_{\lambda \ \ \ \text{(i.e. Poisson Mean)}}=\frac{\lambda}{1-e^{-\lambda}}$$

Similarly, we can find $E[Y^2]$ as $\frac{\lambda+\lambda^2}{1-e^{-\lambda}}$, yielding a variance equation (yours have an extra $\pm$ in the first summand):

$$\operatorname{var}(Y)=\frac{\lambda+\lambda^2}{1-e^{-\lambda}}-\frac{\lambda^2}{(1-e^{-\lambda})^2}$$